# UITapGestureRecognizer is not working with Google Maps SDK

Tags: ios, swift

I have a mapViewController with some custom UIView over it (just two labels with some background). I want to show new ViewController after the tap on this UIView.

So, my code (this was a working solution for other cases) for custom UIView:

```
 tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "checkGesture:")
        tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        self.userInteractionEnabled = true
        self.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
```

and

```
func checkGesture(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("it works")
}
```

Could anyone please tell me what is the problem here?

**Edit (Solved):** So, I tried to put this custom UIView on another ViewController and it works. It seems that main source of this problem is the next part of code in my MapViewController:

```
let mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera:camera)
    self.view = mapView
```

Without the last line (self.view = mapView), my custom UIView works (but I don't have any map, so I had to change this code slightly).

```
let mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height), camera:camera)
    self.view.addSubview(mapView)
```

Comment: Does this still work in swift 3?

Answer (score 5):

I think that best solution if you don't want to add the `GMSMapView` as a subview is:

1. Add `GMSMapViewDelegate` to your `ViewController`.
2. On `viewDidLoad` of your `ViewController` add `myMapView.delegate = self`.
3. Also add the following function:

   ```
   func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapAt coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
       print("!map tapped!")
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is the problem, but change this line

```
tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "checkGesture:")
```

to this

```
tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("checkGesture:"))
```

and report me if its working, or if there are further problems

Comment: no, unfortunately it's not. actually I just tried to put this custom UIView on different ViewController, and it works like a charm (both versions — yours and mine). so it seems there is some conflict between UITapGestureRecognizer and MKMapView.